# If statement inside Repeater control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

Although there are several questions on this topic, I haven't found any satisfactory answers.

I have a Repeater that needs to display complex content. An `IF` statement is required within the template. I can't move this to the code-behind as I need to have server controls and user controls registered within the repeater. Here is what I need:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rCom" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <%# If CBool(Eval("IsFix")) Then%>
           <%-- HTML content including server and user controls --%>
       <%Else%>
           <%-- HTML content including server and user controls --%>
       <%End If%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The above throws a compiler error. Any idea on how to achieve this? I need to evaluate the `IsFix` field in the `If` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put each set of content within a server side panel, then on ItemDataBound event, set the visibility of one panel to true, and the other to false.
If visibility is set server side, then the front end content never even gets rendered.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. However, both panels will also contain databound controls (some common on both panels). How can I ensure that the databound controls of only the visible panel are bound?

Comment: I have some user controls that bind automatically - but I believe I will be able to control that through exposed properties. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `#` from the code nuggets which is having `if` statement:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rCom" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <% CBool(Eval("IsFix")) Then%>
           <%-- HTML content including server and user controls --%>
       <%Else%>
           <%-- HTML content including server and user controls --%>
       <%End If%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Edit:**

Try with conditional operator (I am not sure about the syntax in VB.NET, please check):-

```
<%# If(CBool(Eval("IsFix")), "Do Something", "Else do something" %>
```

Comment: Tried that already. It doesn't work. I get this error when the repeater is bound:  Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: Simple HTML content works fine like this: `<%# If(CBool(Eval("IsFix")),"<div>Is True</div>","<div>Is False</div>")%>`. But I need to have server controls.

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to have server and user controls within the two conditions.

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly!!

```
<%# If(CBool(Eval("bitExtemporaneo")) = True, "<img src=""Imagenes/Extempo.png"" alt=""Extemporaneo""/>", "")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove # from the code where is having if statement.

Then use the code like this.

```
<%
                    object objIsFix = ((System.Data.DataTable)rep.DataSource).Rows[_nIndex]["IsFix"];
                if (bool(objIsFix)) {%>
                <%-- HTML content including server and user controls --%>
                <%}Else{%>
                <%-- HTML content including server and user controls --%>
                <%}%>
```

'_nIndex' is defined in the cs file